って at the end of a sentence: What are all its usage?
A character is scolding another character for taking shortcuts in his life and he screams this
実力があればそんなことしなくてもいいって!
"If you have an ability, you don't need to that" However why is って used? As far I know, no one uttered this before (neither the speaker or the person he's speaking to) so it's not a quote.
what function does  って have in this case?
